# elementary logs out when screen goes blank

Tags: display, greeter, power

When I set my power setting to blank the screen after a set amount of time when the screen goes blank it logs me out of elementary. When I log back in I have to restart my applications.

elementary is a wonderful OS but I just can't see a way of fixing this problem.

This is getting frustrating as if I have a long download or upload I leave it going over night but they have been cut out due to this problem.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be the solution for your problem, but you could try turning of the Screen Lock (normaly it shouldn't exit applications).

Got to System-Settings->Security->Locking:
[image]

Also try to set "Sleep when inactive" to "never" under Energy

Answer (score 1):

You could use Terminal and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

or use dconf editor and go to:

org > gnome > desktop > lockdown

and set  `disable-lock-screen` on true

This way you still can have the screen sleep and also enter suspend but still wake up directly into your desktop (without lock screen).

Comment: PS: If you want to continue the download in background with dimmed screen you should keep "Sleep when inactive" to "never". (In Power settings that is)